# Finding a table (with data) that references a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that has a lot of tables with no data in them. I am wanting to find all of the tables that reference a specific column, but I want to make sure that the tables that show up have data and aren't empty. So far I have been able to show which tables have data using

```
select 
t.name TableName, i.rows Records
from sysobjects t, sysindexes i
where t.xtype = 'U' and i.id = t.id and i.indid in (0,1) AND rows > 0 
order by TableName;
```

I have also been able to show which tables reference the specific column that I am wanting by using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMN_NAME'
```

I just don't know how to combine the two.

Comment: I don't either. One is MSFT sql server, the other is MySQL !

Comment: So maybe you combine the two by taking the source code of both products and creating a third server?

Comment: It should not be difficult. But, your question is not clear for me. Could you please add some data and show us what your desired data is?

Comment: I have a database that references the same column many times. I want to show what tables reference that column, but I only want to show tables that have entries (rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT t.name TableName,
       i.rows Records,
       c.*
FROM sysobjects t
     INNER JOIN sysindexes i ON i.id = t.id
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.name = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.xtype = 'U'
      AND i.indid IN(0, 1)
     AND rows > 0
ORDER BY TableName;
```